# ASP.NET PagedDataSource Paging Property Diffrence

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

What is the difference between

```
(1) AllowServerPaging
(2) AllowCustomPaging
(3) AllowPaging
```

of PagedDataSource ? please explain the situation to pick up the appropriate one.

Answer (score -1):

allow custom paging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.allowcustompaging.aspx

allow server paging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.allowserverpaging.aspx

allow paging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.allowpaging.aspx